# Is there any macro(except declare) for writing functions without think of the order of function declarations in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I want to write functions without think of the order of function declarations, I don't want to use **declare** function because I need to declare all function names  which I don't want to do it.

I want some macro or some function that does the magic for me. Long story short, I need to write functions like Java(method declaration order **does not** matter )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is kind of unneeded, but easily possible as an exercise (up to some point). You can write macro, that would forward declare all the top level functions wrapped in it:

```
(defmacro with-forward-declaration [& body]              
  (let [names (keep #(when (#{'defn 'defn-} (first %))
                       (if (map? (second %)) (nth % 2) (second %)))
                    body)]
    `(do (declare ~@names)
         ~@body)))
```

that is how it is expanded:

```
(with-forward-declaration

  (defn ^long ff1 [x] (* 2 (ff2)))

  (println "just to be sure it doesn't eat other forms")

  (defn ^{:name 'xx} ff2 [] (+ 10 (ff3)))

  (defn ff3 [] 101)

  (defn- ff4 [] :x))
```

would do the following:

```
(do
  (declare ff1 ff2 ff3 ff4)
  (defn ff1 [x] (* 2 (ff2)))
  (println "just to be sure it doesn't eat other forms")
  (defn ff2 [] (+ 10 (ff3)))
  (defn ff3 [] 101)
  (defn- ff4 [] :x))
```

so if you wrap all your namespace's code into this macro, it would predeclare all the functions for you. If you want to go deeper, like predeclaring all some possible `defn`s that are not in the top level, you could update this toy macro by using `clojure.walk` to find these inner forms.. But i guess this one is just enough, to play with clojure quickly, without thinking about functions' order. I wouldn't do that in production though (at least not without the heavy testing).

Comment: This macro is also inflexible, because it doesn't work with raw `def` forms or with other macros that expand into `defn` or `defn-` forms.

Comment: obviously. I just meant to show it is possible. The rest is up to the implementor.

Answer (score 5):

One of the best things I like most about functional programming is, that its flow of writing is the same as the flow of thinking. It's like peeling an onion, and at every moment, I only need to concentrate on working on this single layer, and take the inner part for granted. And don't worry about function names, `foo` and `bar` would be fine at first. In this style of writing, functions are defined and implemented from the end of the source file back to the top. In cases when one function calls multiple other functions, this linear structure becomes a tree-like structure, but there is always a single point in file to insert new functions. No choices and worries.

Yes, there are times when we need to work on some code snippets with no other dependencies. They can be put at the top of the source file of course.

To answer the question upfront, `macros` are not magic. If there exists such a macro, this macro will need to take the whole source file as input, analyze the dependency between each code blocks, and re-flow them in the correct order. The analysis of dependency is non-trivial because of lexical scoping. It's almost like writing a compiler. I don't believe such macro exists (has been written by anyone), and the goods it can do is, well to me, not so big.